# Расположить блоки в очередности сверху-вниз -> слева-направо

Tags: css3, html, javascript, css

Есть фрагмент `html`, например:

```
<div id="x">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
</div>
```

Что-бы заполнить их слева-направо/сверху вниз, достаточно задать контейнеру фиксированую ширину, а внутреним блокам добавить свойство `float:left`. Результат будет таким:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Задача состоит в том, что-бы блоки располагались сначала сверху-вниз, а потом — слева-направо. Тоесть результат должен быть таким:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Как вариант, можно использовать свойство `columns` из `css3`, но существует ли более кроссбраузерное решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ - использовать ещё div-ы, для группирования по три элемента. [Смотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2YS5H/)

```
<div id="some_block">
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#some_block > div{
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
#some_block > div > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Можно не делать такую разметку изначально, а использовать JS для оборачивания этих элементов в доп. div-ы.